# "...жил шмыгая, подслушивая и вынюхивая". Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, деепричастия

**Этот крысенок родился отличным от прочих, в месте, смысл которого никто не пытался понять, и жил шмыгая, подслушивая и вынюхивая.**

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с препинательностью!

Comment: Нет слова "препинательность". Или я уже отстала от жизни?

Comment: Это (мне кажется,мой) окказионализм.))))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всё остается без изменения. **Запятая после "жил" не нужна,** так как однородный ряд из деепричастий тесно связан со сказуемым и не обособляется (он обозначает образ жизни).

Answer (score 3):

Есть такое [**правило**](http://www.konspektov.net/question/1648002):

Не обособляются одиночные деепричастия, обычно непосредственно примыкающие к глаголу-сказуемому и близкие по функции к наречиям образа действия (такие деепричастия отвечают на вопросы: как? каким образом? в каком положении?).
Например: *Он долго не мигая смотрел в одну точку* (О. Форш).

...и жил — **как?** — шмыгая, подслушивая и вынюхивая.

Так что, думаю, пунктуация в Вашем предложении правильна.
Меня только смущает вот этот кусочек: *в месте, смысл которого никто не пытался понять*. Разве у места может быть смысл?

Comment: Допускаю, что в образном мышлении автора, избравшего фокал крысенка, место может приобретать некий смысл. Меня настораживает запятая после "прочих". Вроде она стоит не по правилам. Но если не поставить ее, то в чтении сливается "прочих (в) месте" и возникает сильное недоумение. Мнительное ИМХО))))